# Receiving a List<double> parameter in an url params in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, url, parameters

Is this possible to pass parameter in an URL as a list of double to further read data in the controller something like :

```
/shape?coordinates=[[-73.71813201904297,45.620323181152344],[-73.7154312133789,45.62249755859375],...,[-73.71813201904297,45.620323181152344]]
```

As you understand I need to pass geopoint that define a shape, my POCO is waiting for a `List<List<double>>`

I know I could parse a string like :

```
/shape/coordinates=-73.71813201904297,45.620323181152344|-73.7154312133789,45.62249755859375|,...,|-73.71813201904297,45.620323181152344
```

Comment: sure - what are you using for your app?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. But you can reach limit of URL length if you list is too long. The actual limit is different in particular browsers and servers, you need to seach for particular technology you want to use to know the exact numbers.

If you are concerned in the format: Query string is just a string, you can convert to any object as you wish by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, you can use AJAX and pass your list to it.

```
function SendList() {
        var list = [your list]

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: list,
            url: '@Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController")',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (res) {

            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });
    }
```